# Puppet: nested hash/dict,array: how to access in erb?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, erb, puppet

playing with puppet, I have ended up in a nested dictionary/hash - which looks more or less like

```
$settings =
{
  "var1" => 
  {
    "ip" => "0.0.0.0",
    "port" => "1234",
    "option" => ["foo", "bar"],
    "machines" =>
    {
      "maschine-1" => { "ip" => "1.2.3.4", "port" => "1234"},
      "maschine-2" => { "ip" => "1.2.3.5", "port" => "1235"},
    }  
  }
}
```

however, I have not managed to parse properly it in the correspondig erb template.

```
<% @settings.each_pair do |settings_key, settings_value_hash| %>
<%= settings_value_hash['ip']%>:<%= settings_value_hash['port'] %>

option <% @settings_value_hash['option'].each do |option| -%> <%= option  %>   <% end -%>

<% @{settings_value_hash['machines']}.each_pair do |machine_key, machine_value_hash| %>
  server <%= machine_key %>  <%= machine_value_hash['ip'] %>:<%= machine_value_hash['port'] %>
<% end %>
```

Thus, I can get the values in my top dictionary without problems, i.e., "ip" and "port",

However, puppet throws me compile errors, when I try to get to the array "option" or the dict "machines" within the top dict.

My guess at the moment is, that arrays and dicts/hashes are not "hashable" in Ruby/Puppet, or?

Cheers and thanks for ideas,
  Thomas

Comment: include the error messages you got, that would aid those who want to provide answers

Comment: Hi, the error looks like 


`err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: compile error
    /etc/puppet/workspace/dev/src/modules/haproxy/templates/haproxy_config.erb:93: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting kEND
;  @{settings_value_hash['option']...
    ^
/etc/puppet/workspace/dev/src/modules/haproxy/templates/haproxy_config.erb:93: odd number list for Hash
...settings_value_hash['option']}.each do |option| ; _erbout.co...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing but there a few glaring issues like `@settings_value_hash` is not defined it would be `settings_value_hash` piped variable not instance variable. `@{settings_value_hash['machines']}` is in correct as well what happens if you run this

```
<% @settings.each do |settings_key, settings_value_hash| %>
  <%= "#{settings_value_hash['ip']}:#{settings_value_hash['port']}" %>
  option 
  <% settings_value_hash['option'].each do |option| %> 
    <%= option  %>   
  <% end %>
  <% settings_value_hash['machines'].each do |machine_key, machine_value_hash| %>
    server <%= "#{machine_key} #{machine_value_hash['ip']}:#{machine_value_hash['port']}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Also why is your initial hash set to a global `$settings` but you are accessing it through an instance variable `@settings`.

Comment: That's a Puppet-ism. `$settings =` is an expression from the Puppet DSL. Variables are prefixed with `$` Perl style. In an ERB template evaluated by Puppet, those variables are available as instance variables.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to follow somewhat the Puppet docs, i.e., http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/templates.html#editing-the-templates 
(with the each_pair erb-expression googled somewhere)
Anyway, your proposed solution works fine :)

Comment: @Thomas no problem `each_pair` is just an alias for `each` in a `Hash` structure so feel free to use `each_pair` as it will function the same.